# how to exit app from fragment use kotlin in android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have 2 activities, main and splash, main will contain 3 fragments, signIn, signUp and Home, I want when in signIn and home press the back button to exit the app

Answer (score 1):

at splash after startActivity(intent) just call finish(). When in fragments that want to exit, they need to call activity.finish()